# Tabs com diferentes Query's PHP

Tags: php

Estou com dificuldade em criar uma pagina com duas Tabs mas cada uma com uma query diferente.

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">TAB1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">TAB2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <?php

      include("conectar.php");

echo'<div id="tabs-1">
$sql = "select * from Tabelas
where Campo1 and campo2"';
echo'   $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())';
echo'   while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){

     <li class="ui-widget-content"><h3><a href="NaoautorizadoMostrar.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">'.$exibe['Nome'].'</h3></a></li>;
  } </div>';


    echo'<div id="tabs-2">
$sql = "select * from Tabelas
where Campo3 and campo4"';
echo'   $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())';
echo'   while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){

     <li class="ui-widget-content"><h3><a href="NaoautorizadoMostrar.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">'.$exibe['Nome'].'</h3></a></li>;
  } </div>';
```

erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: exibe in.

Obrigado

Comment: pelo erro que você postou, a variável "exibe" não foi definida. Onde você define a variável "exibe"?

Comment: Está dando muitos erros de sintaxe por você tratar comando php como string e querer exibi-las

Answer (score 1):

Não fica claro qual conteúdo você quer exibir na aba. Também seria interessante você informar qual biblioteca javascript você está usando pra criar as abas.

Busque ser um pouco mais organizado, isso facilitará a identificação de erros e manutenção do seu código.

1. Evite utilizar echo para gerar conteúdo HTML, isso dificulta a leitura do código.
2. Também evite inserir consultas no meio do seu código HTML, tente centralizar as consultas no início do script ou de preferência adote um [framework MVC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC).
3. Do ponto de vista do HTML, seu código está errado. Ele possui LIs sem OL/UL pais.
4. Como o HTML de cada aba é igual, você pode colocar os conteúdos de cada aba em um array e gerar as diferentes abas através de um foreach, sem precisar repetir código.

Segue minha sugestão de organização:

```
<?php
include("conectar.php"); 

// Dados da tab1
$sql = "select * from Tabelas where Campo1 and campo2";
$rs1 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// Dados da tab2
$sql = "select * from Tabelas where Campo3 and campo4";
$rs2 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// Tabs
$tabs = array($rs1, $rs2);     
?>
<html>
...
   <!-- Geração do HTML dos links para as tabs -->
   <ul>   
        <?php $c = 1;?>
        <?php foreach($tabs as $rs):?>
            <li><a href="#tab-<?php echo $c;?>">Aba <?php echo $c; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ul>

   <!-- Geração do HTML do CONTEUDO das tabs -->
   <?php $c = 1;?>
   <?php foreach($tabs as $rs):?>
      <div id="tabs-<?php echo $c++;?>">
          <!-- Conteúdo da aba. -->
          <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)): ?>                    
              <?php echo $row['Nome'];?>
          <?php endwhile;?>
      </div>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Seu código está desestruturado, acho que assim resolve seu problema:

```
<?php

      include("conectar.php");

echo '<div id="tabs-1">';
$sql = "select * from Tabelas where Campo1 and campo2";
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){

    echo '<li class="ui-widget-content"><h3><a href="NaoautorizadoMostrar.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">'.$exibe['Nome'].'</h3></a></li>';
  }
 echo '</div>';


   echo'<div id="tabs-2">';
 $sql = "select * from Tabelas where Campo3 and campo4";
 $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){

    echo '<li class="ui-widget-content"><h3><a href="NaoautorizadoMostrar.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">'.$exibe['Nome'].'</h3></a></li>';
  } 

  echo '</div>';
```